# Why does this code generate an exception?

Tags: android, camera

I'm a beginner in Android developing and i'm trying to make a camera application.
I put all of the code in pastebin; here are links:

Main.java: [here](http://pastebin.com/Eb9Vg96Q)

CameraControl.java: [here](http://pastebin.com/6WQ75wbH)

CameraPreview.java: [here](http://pastebin.com/vrdUGfV5)

The code is a little messy, but i hope you can read it.

Here is the exception message from logcat:

```
08-30 17:31:48.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 17:31:48.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2558): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 17:31:48.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at com.maccer.vidcamtest.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:25)
08-30 17:31:48.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
08-30 17:31:48.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-30 17:31:48.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-30 17:31:48.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-30 17:31:48.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-30 17:31:48.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-30 17:31:48.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 17:31:48.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-30 17:31:48.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
08-30 17:31:48.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
08-30 17:31:48.299: E/AndroidRuntime(2558):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the `Exception` (e.g. a logcat dump).

Comment: Also, try to post the relevant code here. Pastebin is cool and all, but not only is it blocked on some networks, but it's more visible here.

Comment: At least please write it correctly.. it is NOT an expection !!!! You didn't make the mistake once but twice >.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Main, you have a field:

```
    private CameraControl cc;
```

which is never initialized; therefore it's null when you try to use it in your callback. That is, trying to call

```
cc.safeCameraOpen()
```

when `cc` is null causes a NullPointerException.

Comment: How to initialize that?

Comment: In your `onCreate` method, you could add the line: `cc = new CameraControl();`

Comment: You're going to have a similar problem in `CameraControl`, where the `mPreview` field is not initialized. You might want to read up a bit on initializing variables and fields in Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        cc.safeCameraOpen(); //<<--------------------------------------
    }
});
```

}

You never set any value for `cc` so it is null and You get NPE.